# Show that $g(X_n)\to g(c)$ in probability.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $X_n$ a sequence of random variables so that $X_n\to c$ in probability as $n\to \infty$. Suppose that $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=c$. Show that $g(X_n)\to g(c)$ in probability.

My proof: Since $g(x)$ is continuous at $x=c$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$, we have $|g(x)-g(c)|<\epsilon$.

Fix $\epsilon>0$,
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} P(|g(X_n)-g(c)|>\epsilon)\le \lim_{n\to \infty} P(|X_n-c|>\delta)=0
$$

Is my proof right?

---

I saw the answer. It says that let $A_n=\{|g(X_n)-g(c)|<\epsilon\}$ and $B_n=\{|X_n-c|<\delta\}$. Note that $B_n\subset A_n$.
$$
P(A_n)=P(A_n, B_n)+P(A_n, B_n^c)\le 
$$

Comment: It is corect but $>\delta$ should be $\geq \delta$ in your inequality.

Comment: @geetha290krm How about the approach in the answer? It seems that they are two different method?

Comment: Another approach is to use the following well known result: $X_n$ converges to $X$ iff any subsequence $X_{n'}$ of $X_n$ admits a subsequence $X_{n''}$ that converges to $X$ almost surely.