# Show that $g(X_n, Y_n)\to g(c, d)$ in probability.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Following this question: [Show that $g(X_n)\to g(c)$ in probability.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4638162/show-that-gx-n-to-gc-in-probability).

Let $X_n, Y_n$ be two sequences of random variables so that $X_n\to c, Y_n\to d$ in probability as $n\to \infty$. Suppose that $g(x, y)$ is continuous at $x=c$. Show that $g(X_n, Y_n)\to g(c, d)$ in probability.

How to prove that? I check the continuity of two variables of function in https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Calculus_3e_(Apex)/12%3A_Functions_of_Several_Variables/12.02%3A_Limits_and_Continuity_of_Multivariable_Functions.

So is the proof same as [Show that $g(X_n)\to g(c)$ in probability.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4638162/show-that-gx-n-to-gc-in-probability)?

Comment: We have $(X_n, Y_n) \to (c,d)$ in probability and hence $g(X_n, Y_n) \to g(c,d)$ in probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use $$||(x,y)-(c,d)|| > \delta \implies |x-c| > \frac{\delta}{2} \text{ or } |y-d| >\frac{\delta}{2} $$ Hence by continuity of $g$ at $(c,d)$, $$P(|g(X_n,Y_n)-g(c,d)| > \epsilon ) \leq P( ||(X_n,Y_n)-(c,d)|| > \delta ) \leq P( |X_n-c|> \frac{\delta}{2} \text{ or } |Y_n-d|> \frac{\delta}{2}) \leq P(|X_n -c|>  \frac{\delta}{2}) + P(|Y_n-d| > \frac{\delta}{2}) \rightarrow 0$$